# Can I use a mock File in my Specs2 test for writing to a file? If so, How?

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, mockito, specs2

I've successfully used Specs2 to test serialization to a file, but the test uses a real file (written to /tmp/). I'd rather not touch disk just for a test.  Is there a way to use a mocked file?

```
def serializeAndDeserializeFromDatafile[X <: CaseClass : Manifest](old: X, maybeGrater: Option[AvroGrater[X]] = None): X = {
val g = maybeGrater.getOrElse(grater[X])

//val outfile = mock[File]
val outfile = new File("/tmp/file1.avro")   

g.serializeToDataFile(outfile, old)  //Serialize to file

val infile = outfile
g.asObjectFromDataFile(infile)       //Deserialize from file 
}
```

I tried using Mockito to mock my `outfile`(the commented-out line above).  In my naive attempt, I can create the `Mock for File, hashCode: 1583021903`, but it seems to be `null` when I try to serialize.

I think I'm missing a 'stub' of some sort, but I can't find any examples that are similar enough to suggest a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a program (an autonomous written using Akka) that deals extensively in file system operations. I wrote it using ScalaIO (rather than native Java library `java.io._` classes). ScalaIO includes, among other things, the `RamFileSystem` which allows you to mock file system contents and operations in ways that mirror real file system operations without involving file-system and I/O system calls.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This is what I was hoping for, but I quickly stumbled: `val fs = new RamFileSystem(separator="/")
    println("filesys: " + fs)
  val path = fs("/tmp/", '/')
    println("path: " + path)     println("isFile "+ path.isFile)
    val mockedFile = path.createFile()
      println("mockedFile " + mockedFile)
      println("isFile " + mockedFile.isFile)
    val outfile= mockedFile.fileOption
      println("outfile: " + outfile)` tells me that `mockedFile` is a file, but the `outfile: Option[File]` is a `PathType`, thus returning `None` instead of the needed `java.io.File`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  tl;dr: Should I expect to be able to get a `java.io.File` from this kind of mock (e.g. a `RamPath`)?

Comment: No. How could it? It would have to have an OS-level file system driver to do that. But ScalaIO is a much richer API for I/O and file operations.

Comment: Ahh, now I think I see. I'd extend or re-write the appropriate class using ScalaIO, and then in this test, I could simply substitute the `RamFileSystem` for the default one.

Comment: Precisely. My experience so far, which is not incredibly extensive, is that it works quite well. If your FS and IO interactions are injectable or mockable, you can readily devise tests that don't involve physical files at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock out a `File` but that doesn't mean that things are going to work ok. By default, when you call a method on a mock, it returns `null` (or 0 for an `int` value for example).

So if the function you are testing calls one of the `File` methods you will need to provide sensible default values. For example:

```
val f = mock[File]

f.createNewFile returns true
f.isFile returns true
f.list returns Array("child1", "child2")
```

That being said, if your `grater` object really needs a functional file to write to, it might be impossible to really mock this.

Comment: This is half a non-answer :). Can you please elaborate where the `null` comes from?

Comment: This is already helpful to me:) I'm no expert, so the only thing I can currently add RE the `null`, is that the error thrown is a serialization exception of Salat-Avro, in `SingleAvroGrater.scala` (primarily deals with "indexed fields", but not file creation or setting the values of fields). And if I set the default return value of `mock[File]` to `None`, the compiler complains that it can't be cast to a java `Boolean` (I stopped there). Thanks to your example I now see that there is extensive difficulty in mocking this way, and a real file is sounding more acceptable. And thanks for Specs2!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try use OutputStream/InputStream instead of files?

Example:

```
val out:OutputStream = null
// val testOut  = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
// val realOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/file1.avro"))

g.serializeToOutputStream(out, old)  //Serialize to file

val in:InputStream = null
// val testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(testOut.toByteArray)
// val realIn = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/file1.avro"))

g.asObjectFromInputStream(in)       //Deserialize from file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so: the underlying classes only take a `File`. At least it's not *obvious* how 'mock' in the way you suggest. Prior to using Specs2 for testing this, I tried to 'mock' a stream like how you suggest, but got bogged down trying to read record boundaries from binary without a `datafilereader`. Using the lower-level Avro classes to write avros is/looks very different, and I already have tests for such serialization. Here I need to test this component and its use of underlying high-level `datafilewriter/datafilereader` class methods. Maybe mock those classes instead?

Comment: Hmm, maybe my previous effort didn't work for streams of avros that wouldn't fit in memory, but for this small test, I will try again... Still would love to know how to use Mockito however!